# Show that the image of Gaussian map of a generalized cone is a curve on $S^2$ and deduce that the cone has zero Gaussian curvature.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

Show that the image of Gaussian map of a generalized cone is a curve on $S^2$ and deduce that the cone has zero Gaussian curvature.

I dont have enough idea. Please explain the question clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint/Answer in the wrong language: [P] 8.1.7 of http://maths.fuglede.dk/MA4F13/u13.pdf, page 3.

Comment: It seems good explanation. But I cannot understand the language. Can you write the answer here please:)